# ctrl + w for close window?

Tags: settings, release-juno

I'm new to elementary OS, I was using Linux Mint and now I'm moved to elementary OS since Juno was released.. I often use ctrl + w for close window in Linux Mint (It's default on Linux Mint), can I use this shortcut in Juno for close window? because when I see keyboard setting I dont have "Close Window" command in the list..

Comment: I too noticed the same! Ctrl-Q works for some! But not for all. Fox example, it doesnt close Epiphany (browser) but it works for Files

Comment: @JayAurabind wow true, I'm just tried using Ctrl-Q and it work but only for files..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- **Ctrl-W**  - is normally the **close-tab** short-key, and it works in tabbed apps like browsers and file managers, the last-tab closed closing the program or defaulting to the startup tab; Files stays open when last tab is closed (a setting that can be also enabled in Firefox: `about:config`, then set `browser.tabs.closeWindowWithLastTab` to `false`).
- **Ctrl-T** - is the complementary to the above: the **open-new-tab** short-key. The Juno terminal will not follow these two shortcuts thought.
- And there is the universal **Alt-F4** that applies to **all** windows whatsoever.
- **Ctrl-Q** - operates like the above, closing **all** windows - with very rare exceptions: Epiphany, mentioned in @JayAurabind's comment.

Comment: Any ideas on how to change this for evince. There `CTRL+Q` is not closing the application.

Comment: @dietervdf - you should post a specific question on that. right now I'm not using Evince, nor elementary.

Comment: @dietervdf - Maybe there are some settings in dconf editor in its options for gala, which is the window manager. I cannot test write now as I'm in lxqt for the moment, but I will take a look as soon as possible.